# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value_counts' even array is given

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

this is my input

```
df['class'].value_counts()[1]/df['class'].value_counts()[0]
```

what I get as error is:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value_counts'
```

since I signed a array tp .value_counts, I don't now why its not working.

defining df:

```
df = pd.read_csv('credit-g.csv')
```

source comes from preprocessed https://datahub.io/machine-learning/credit-g.

```
df.columns
```

returns:

```
['checking_status', 'duration', 'credit_history', 'purpose',
       'credit_amount', 'savings_status', 'employment',
       'installment_commitment', 'personal_status', 'other_parties',
       'residence_since', 'property_magnitude', 'age', 'other_payment_plans',
       'housing', 'existing_credits', 'job', 'num_dependents', 'own_telephone',
       'foreign_worker', 'class']
```

There you can see, 'class' exists.

Comment: What does `df` look like? Please provide a sample of your dataset.

Comment: Please show the part of the code that you think ought to make it work.

Comment: df = pd.read_csv('credit-g.csv'), it's pretty simple. credit-g is an open source training set: https://datahub.io/machine-learning/credit-g